# Handling "InterfaceError: another operation is in progress" with Async SQLAlchemy and FastAPI

Tags: python, asynchronous, fastapi, sqlmodel

I'm developing a FastAPI application where I use SQLModel with the `asyncpg` driver for asynchronous database operations. Despite following the asynchronous patterns and ensuring proper await usage on database calls, I encounter the following error during my `pytest` tests:

`InterfaceError: cannot perform operation: another operation is in progress`

This error arises when executing database operations, seemingly due to concurrent access or overlapping database transactions. I've tried ensuring that each test and request uses its own `AsyncSession` and that all sessions and transactions are properly closed and committed.

```
import random
import string

import pytest
import pytest_asyncio
from httpx import AsyncClient, ASGITransport

from main import app  # Make sure this import points to your FastAPI app instance


@pytest_asyncio.fixture
async def client():
    async with AsyncClient(transport=ASGITransport(app=app), base_url="http://test") as client:
        yield client


@pytest_asyncio.fixture
def generate_random_phone_number():
    def _generate(length=10):
        return ''.join(random.choices(string.digits, k=length))

    return _generate


@pytest_asyncio.fixture
def generate_random_phone_prefix():
    def _generate():
        prefix_length = random.randint(1, 3)
        return '+' + ''.join(random.choices(string.digits, k=prefix_length))

    return _generate


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_create_user(client: AsyncClient, generate_random_phone_number, generate_random_phone_prefix):
    user_data = {
        "phone_number": generate_random_phone_number(),
        "phone_prefix": generate_random_phone_prefix()
    }

    response = await client.post("/api/user/", json=user_data)

    assert response.status_code == 201
    data = response.json()
    assert data["phone_number"] == user_data["phone_number"]
    assert data["phone_prefix"] == user_data["phone_prefix"]


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_duplicate_user(client: AsyncClient, generate_random_phone_number, generate_random_phone_prefix):
    phone_number = generate_random_phone_number()
    phone_prefix = generate_random_phone_prefix()
    user_data = {
        "phone_number": phone_number,
        "phone_prefix": phone_prefix
    }

    await client.post("/api/user/", json=user_data)
    response = await client.post("/api/user/", json=user_data)

    assert response.status_code == 400
    data = response.json()
    assert data["detail"] == "A user with the given phone number and prefix already exists."


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_create_interest(client: AsyncClient, generate_random_phone_number, generate_random_phone_prefix):
    # First, create a user
    user_data = {
        "phone_number": generate_random_phone_number(),
        "phone_prefix": generate_random_phone_prefix()
    }
    user_response = await client.post("/api/user/", json=user_data)
    assert user_response.status_code == 201
    user = user_response.json()

    interest_data = {
        "topic": "Sample Topic",
        "found": 1,
        "search": True
    }

    headers = {"User-ID": str(user["id"])}

    response = await client.post("/api/interest/", json=interest_data, headers=headers)

    assert response.status_code == 201
    interest = response.json()
    assert interest["topic"] == interest_data["topic"]
    assert interest["found"] == interest_data["found"]
    assert interest["search"] == interest_data["search"]


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_get_interest(client: AsyncClient, generate_random_phone_number, generate_random_phone_prefix):
    user_data = {
        "phone_number": generate_random_phone_number(),
        "phone_prefix": generate_random_phone_prefix()
    }
    user_response = await client.post("/api/user/", json=user_data)
    assert user_response.status_code == 201
    user = user_response.json()
    headers = {"User-ID": str(user["id"])}

    interest_1 = {
        "topic": "Sample Topic1",
        "found": 1,
        "search": True
    }
    response = await client.post("/api/interest/", json=interest_1, headers=headers)
    assert response.status_code == 201

    interest_2 = {
        "topic": "Sample Topic2",
        "found": 0,
        "search": True
    }

    response = await client.post("/api/interest/", json=interest_2, headers=headers)
    assert response.status_code == 201

    response = await client.get("/api/interest/", headers=headers)
    interests = response.json()
    assert len(interests) == 2
    # Validate the content of the first interest object
    interest_1_response = interests[0]
    assert interest_1_response["topic"] == "Sample Topic1"
    assert interest_1_response["found"] == 1
    assert interest_1_response["search"] is True
    assert "created_at" in interest_1_response
    assert "updated_at" in interest_1_response
    assert interest_1_response["created_at"] <= interest_1_response["updated_at"]

    # Validate the content of the second interest object
    interest_2_response = interests[1]
    assert interest_2_response["topic"] == "Sample Topic2"
    assert interest_2_response["found"] == 0
    assert interest_2_response["search"] is True
    assert "created_at" in interest_2_response
    assert "updated_at" in interest_2_response
    assert interest_2_response["created_at"] <= interest_2_response["updated_at"]
```

I've also ensured that my `AsyncClient` for testing is properly set up and that each test function is marked with `@pytest.mark.asyncio` to run in an async context.

I'm looking for insights or solutions to properly handle this error and ensure that my asynchronous database operations don't conflict with each other.

**Update**
Here are all the codes.
Endpoints:

```
@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan():
    await init_db()


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)
allowed_origins = [
    "http://127.0.0.1:5173",
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=allowed_origins,  # List of allowed origins
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],  # Allows all methods
    allow_headers=["*"],  # Allows all headers
)


def user_id_from_header(user_id: str = Header(...)) -> str:
    if not user_id:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="User-ID is missing")
    return user_id


# Health
@app.get("/")
async def health():
    return {"health": "ok"}


# User
@app.get("/api/user/{user_id}", status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK, response_model=UserRead)
async def get_user(*, session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_session), user_id: uuid.UUID):
    user = await session.get(User, user_id)
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="User not found")
    return user


@app.post("/api/user/", response_model=UserRead, status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
async def create_user(*, user_create: UserCreate, session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_session)):
    existing_user = await session.exec(
        select(User).where(
            User.phone_number == user_create.phone_number,
            User.phone_prefix == user_create.phone_prefix
        )
    )
    if existing_user.first():
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=400,
            detail="A user with the given phone number and prefix already exists."
        )

    db_user = User.model_validate(user_create)
    session.add(db_user)
    await session.commit()
    await session.refresh(db_user)
    return db_user


# Interest

@app.post("/api/interest/", response_model=InterestRead, status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
async def create_interest(*, interest_create: InterestCreate, session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_session),
                          user_id: uuid.UUID = Depends(user_id_from_header)):
    user = await session.get(User, user_id)
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="User not found")

    db_interest = Interest(**interest_create.model_dump(), user=user)
    session.add(db_interest)
    await session.commit()
    await session.refresh(db_interest)
    return db_interest


@app.get("/api/interest/", response_model=List[InterestRead])
async def read_interests(*, user_id: uuid.UUID = Depends(user_id_from_header),
                         session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_session)):
    interests = select(Interest).where(Interest.user_id == user_id)
    results = await session.exec(interests)
    return results
```

DB connector

```
engine = create_async_engine("postgresql+asyncpg://xxxxxxxxx:xxxx@127.0.0.1:5432/dobotsvc", echo=True, future=True)


async def init_db():
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        # await conn.run_sync(SQLModel.metadata.drop_all)
        await conn.run_sync(SQLModel.metadata.create_all)


async def get_session() -> AsyncSession:
    async_session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False)
    async with async_session() as session:
        yield session
```

and models

```
class UserBase(SQLModel):
    id: UUID = Field(default_factory=uuid4, primary_key=True)
    phone_number: str = Field(max_length=255)
    phone_prefix: str = Field(max_length=10)


class User(UserBase, table=True):
    __table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint("phone_number", "phone_prefix", name="phone_numbe_phone_prefix_constraint"),
    )
    registered_at: datetime = Field(sa_column=sa.Column(sa.DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False),
                                    default_factory=lambda: datetime.now(timezone.utc))
    interests: List["Interest"] = Relationship(back_populates="user")


class UserRead(UserBase):
    pass


class UserCreate(UserBase):
    pass


class InterestBase(SQLModel):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    topic: str = Field(max_length=100)
    found: int = 0
    search: bool = Field(default=False)
    created_at: datetime = Field(sa_column=sa.Column(sa.DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False),
                                 default_factory=lambda: datetime.now(timezone.utc))
    updated_at: datetime = Field(sa_column=sa.Column(sa.DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False),
                                 default_factory=lambda: datetime.now(timezone.utc))


class Interest(InterestBase, table=True):
    user_id: UUID = Field(foreign_key="user.id")
    user: User = Relationship(back_populates="interests")

    proposals: List["Proposal"] = Relationship(back_populates="interest")


class InterestCreate(InterestBase):
    pass


class InterestRead(InterestBase):
    pass


class ProposalBase(SQLModel):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    interest_id: int = Field(foreign_key="interest.id")
    created_at: datetime = Field(default_factory=lambda: datetime.now(timezone.utc))
    text: str


class Proposal(ProposalBase, table=True):
    interest: Interest = Relationship(back_populates="proposals")
```

Comment: As you said, this error occurs when 2 statements are executed concurrently by one `AsyncSession`. It would be better if you share code related to `AsyncSession`, but most probably you are either using same AsyncSession for 2 concurrent requests (which you say you do not), or you are using `asyncio.gather(...)` or multiple `asyncio.create_task()` (or other ways of concurrency),  that use same `AsyncSession` object, inside one request.

Comment: @sudden_appearance I have provided all the codes.